# Posthoc (planned) comparisons as contrasts between different levels of a regressor, in fitlme (Matlab)

Tags: regression, matlab, post-hoc, contrasts

I have participant data for 5 different rating dimensions (A to E), and I have fitted linear mixed-effects models, separately for each rating, with several fixed- and random-effects predictors:

```
tbl = table(M.rating_A, M.groupSize, M.cond, M.rep, M.training, M.id_rater, M.melody,         'VariableNames',{'ratings' 'groupSize' 'cond' 'rep' 'training'      'id_rater' 'melody'});

formula = 'ratings ~ groupSize + cond + rep + training +         (1|id_rater) + (1|melody)';
lme.rating_A = fitlme(tbl,formula);
```

I'm interested in running post-hoc (planned) comparisons between the different levels of some of those predictors, e.g. see if one type of learning condition (`cond`) leads to higher rating_A scores thann another type.

To that end, I tried to define contrasts with [coefTest](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/linearmodel.coeftest.html), as shown [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/185041-how-can-i-run-post-hoc-tests-for-a-mixed-effects-model-using-fitlme). I'm probably misunderstanding how the contrast vector is coded, but those contrasts appear to compare regressors to one another, isntead of different levels of a single regressor?!

In any case, the stats reported in my `fitlme` results suggest the regressors are treated as continuous instead of the categorical variables they in fact are, so I converted all variables from double to categorical or string, but then fitlme wont accept them as inputs:

```
M_categ = convertvars(M,{'groupSize', 'cond', 'rep', 'id_rater','melody'},"string"); % same if converting to categorical, or cellstr
tbl = table(M_categ.rating_A, M_categ.groupSize, M_categ.cond, M_categ.rep, M_categ.training, M_categ.id_rater, M_categ.melody,         'VariableNames',{'ratings' 'groupSize' 'cond' 'rep' 'training'      'id_rater' 'melody'});

Error using classreg.regr.lmeutils.StandardLinearLikeMixedModel/validateInputs
```

I then attempted the same by using `nominal()`, which still gives an error:

```
tbl = table(M.rating_A, nominal(M.groupSize), nominal(M.cond), nominal(M.rep), M.training, nominal(M.id_rater), nominal(M.melody),         'VariableNames',{'ratings' 'groupSize' 'cond' 'rep' 'training'      'id_rater' 'melody'});
lme.rating_A = fitlme(tbl,formula);

Fixed Effects design matrix X must be of full column rank.
```

So I'm confused: do I need to run the LME using some function other than `fitlme`? Or do I need to call `fitlme` with different parameters (e.g. different dummy codings), that later allow comparing levels within any one given regressor?

Comment: `Fixed Effects design matrix X must be of full column rank.` is indicative of issues with the matrix design, do you include an intercept?

Comment: Not deliberately. Is it not included by default in the above model formula?

Comment: Most likely it is so it causes the rank-deficiency. Do check your factor levels carefully.